# Difference between two dateTimes in seconds vary due to different time zones - Swift 3

Tags: swift, datetime, timezone, swift3, date-difference

I need to find difference between current time (in seconds) and future start time (fetched from my web service in seconds).
I have coded the following :

```
    let currentTime = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    var time = Int64(timeArr[indexPath.row])

    print("\(currentTime) vs \(time)")
    time = time - currentTime
    print("difference in time : \(time)")

    let seconds = time % 60
    let minutes = (time / 60) % 60
    let hours = (time / 3600)
```

My console shows me this output:

```
1480400929 vs 1480552620
difference in time : 151691
```

The problem is that my current time is `Tue Nov 29 2016 11:58:49` and the start time is `2016-11-30 17:37:00` so the difference in hours should come to around 30 hours whereas it takes the times in different time zones due to which it comes to around 42 hours. How do I fix this? I have gone through many questions for the same but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NSDate is an absolute point in time, without any time zone information. 1480400929 is "29 Nov 2016 06:28:49 GMT" and 1480552620 is "1 Dec 2016 00:37:00 GMT". The difference between these times is about 42 hours. – Please explain what result you expect and *why.*

Comment: I want the difference between my current time which was Tue Nov 29 2016 11:58:49 and the start time 2016-11-30 17:37:00 which I am fetching from the server

Comment: Do you get the server time as a string? How do you convert that string to a NSDate? What is the servers time zone? What is your time zone?

Comment: Yes I get it as a string in the form of milliseconds as 1480552620000. I convert that to int64 through this line mentioned above : var time = Int64(timeArr[indexPath.row]). My time zone is GMT + 5:30

Comment: The timestamp 1480552620 sent from the server is "2016-12-01 00:37:00 GMT" and that is "2016-12-01 06:07:00" in your GMT+5:30 time zone, not "2016-11-30 17:37:00"

Comment: I can also fetch the date and time from the web service as a string. Can you tell me how to convert that in date format and use it for the same purpose.

Comment: Sending a time stamp is fine. But why do you think that 1480552620 (or 1480552620000) sent from server is "2016-11-30 17:37:00"? How is the time stamp generated on the server?

Comment: I can fetch this from the server : 2016-11-30 17:37:00 So can you help me with converting this to date format and doing the same process as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the difference between two date in `Hours`, `Minutes` and `seconds` you can use `DateComponent` like this.

```
let component = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: startDate)
let hours = component.hour ?? 0
let minutes = component.minute ?? 0
let seconds = component.second ?? 0
```

**Edit:** To get date from miliseconds use `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` like this.

```
let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: miliSeconds / 1000)
```

Also you can convert string to Date using `DateFormatter` like this.

```
let stringDate = "2016-11-30 17:37:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
if let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate) {
    print(startDate)
}
```

Comment: I am getting my startDate in the form of milliseconds so will this work in that case?

Comment: @Dia In that case you can get start date like this `let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: miliSeconds / 1000)` also check the edited answer.

Comment: let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeArr[indexPath.row]))
        let component = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: startDate)
        let hours = component.hour ?? 0
        let minutes = component.minute ?? 0
        let seconds = component.second ?? 0
I tried this. It still shows 42 hours

Comment: I am getting this in startDate : 2016-12-01 00:37:00 +0000

Comment: @Dia I'm talking about timeInterval not date, show me your timeinterval value from that array

Comment: The array contains 1480552620000 at this index

Comment: Yes it works. Just a small issue more. How do I set timezone to local timezone?

Comment: @Dia Simply `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.local`.

Comment: @Dia Welcome mate :)